# IF function in excel is too long. How to simplify?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-2003, simplify

I have written a long If function in a Cell in an `Excel 2003` worksheet.

I wish to add to it but, Excel is telling me that my function is too long.

Does anybody know how to simplify or reduce the length of the function?

In `Column K3`, I have a drop down list of Types of Defect, then this IF function is in column L3 to appear a specific Defect Description based on the Types of Defects selected in `column K3`.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(K3)=TRUE,IF(OR(K3="Abnormal Finishing",K3="Bending Mark",K3="Bent",K3="Contamination",K3="Crack",K3="Damage",K3="Dented",K3="Discoloration",K3="Finger Print",K3="Flow Mark",K3="Gap",K3="Insufficient Paint",K3="Scratches",K3="Rusty",K3="Stain Mark",K3="Standoff Mark",K3="Tool Mark",K3="Warpage",K3="Water Mark",K3="White Mark",K3="White Spot"),"Cosmetic",IF(OR(K3="Angle Out",K3="Dimension Out",K3="Fitting Problem"),"Dimension",IF(OR(K3="Assembly Misalignment",K3="Fan Broken",K3="Fan Not Functioning",K3="Assembly Wrong Orientation",K3="Missing Component",K3="Missing Rivet (Assembly)",K3="Part Warping (Assembly)",K3="Rivet Loose (Drop) (Assembly)",K3="Rivet Wrong Location (Assembly)",K3="Rivet Wrong Orientation (Assembly)",K3="Screw Loose (Drop)",K3="Screw Stuck"),"Assembly","ERROR"))),"ERROR")
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to make separate lists and check if `K3` exists in the list. For example make a list in any column (J here) for

1. Abnormal Finishing
2. Bending Mark
3. Bent
4. Contamination

use this formula to check if your value in K3 exists in this list

`=IFERROR(MATCH(K3,J11:J14,0)>0,FALSE)`

`J11:J14` is my list. The formula results in `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Your final formula would look like

```
=IF(ISTEXT(K3),IF(IFERROR(MATCH(K3,L3:L7,0)>0,FALSE),"Cosmetic",IF(IFERROR(MATCH(K3,M3:M7,0)>0,FALSE),"Dimension",IF(IFERROR(MATCH(K3,N3:N7,0)>0,FALSE),"Assembly","ERROR"))),"ERROR")
```

where

`L3:L7`, `M3:M7`, `N3:N7` are lists for Domestic, Dimension and Assembly criteria

This could be firther worked upon.

Comment: And one advantage to this solution is that it is easy to add items to each list.

Comment: If you are doing lists, you could also do something like on `Column J` the defect and on `Column K` the type. So a simple `IFERROR()` with a `VLOOKUP` inside would also be easy to add items and it would shorten the formula even more

Answer (score 0):

I usually find that multiple `IF` statements can be avoided using a `VLOOKUP` function. You need your conditions and results in a table like this:

Paste into **A4:A39**

```
Abnormal Finishing
Bending Mark
Bent
Contamination
Crack
Damage
Dented
Discoloration
Finger Print
Flow Mark
Gap
Insufficient Paint
Scratches
Rusty
Stain Mark
Standoff Mark
Tool Mark
Warpage
Water Mark
White Mark
White Spot
Angle Out
Dimension Out
Fitting Problem
Assembly Misalignment
Fan Broken
Fan Not Functioning
Assembly Wrong Orientation
Missing Component
Missing Rivet (Assembly)
Part Warping (Assembly)
Rivet Loose (Drop) (Assembly)
Rivet Wrong Location (Assembly)
Rivet Wrong Orientation (Assembly)
Screw Loose (Drop)
Screw Stuck
```

Paste into **B4:B39**

```
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Cosmetic
Dimension
Dimension
Dimension
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
Assembly
```

Then you can use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K3,$A$4:$B$39,2,0),"ERROR")
```